# Застревание в коллайдерах Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем, создал стену белыми спрайтами, на них висит 2dBoxCollider, на самом объекте Rigidbody и 2dBoxCollider. 
[image: Game scene]
При движение вдоль стен по внутреннему радиусу спрайт начинает застревать в местах, аналогичных показанному на скриншоте выше. И еще непонятные расстояния между коллайдерами, т.е. объекты соприкасаются, зеленый спрайт ближе к стене не едет, а расстояние есть.
[image: Collision view]
Передвигается зеленый квадрат с помощью такого вот скрипта:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject player;
public float speed;


void FixedUpdate () {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += (Vector2.up * speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += (Vector2.down * speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += (Vector2.left * speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += (Vector2.right * speed);
    }

}
}
```

Передвигал и AddForce, и изменяя velocity, такая же байда. 
в чем может быть проблема застревания и расстояния между коллайдерами?

Answer (score 2):

Использовать `velocity` не хорошая идея. По хорошему управление должно осуществляться физикой через `AddForce`. Для того чтобы ваш зеленый квадрат не проникал через другие коллайдеры поправьте в свойствах `Rigidbody` зеленого квадрата поля `Interpolate` и `Collision Detection`. Изменяя значения эксперементируйте и добьетесь чтобы объект меньше делал проникновений в другие коллайдеры.

Также влиять на дискретность смещения может масштаб ваших квадратов. Объекты 10см и объекты 1м по разному обрабатываются движком, поскольку Unity считает в своих единицах (1unit = 1м). Сделав объекты меньше вы сталкиваетесь с проблемой что физика считается для больших объектов.

Помимо этого лучше управление считывать в `Update` в промежуточную переменную, а затем в `FixedUpdate` по ней рассчитывать смещение. Дело в том, что между одним кадром может быть несколько вызовов расчета физики, и ваш код может выполняться неравномерно.

И последнее: при расчете смещения ориентируясь на скорость не забывайте пересчитывать вашу скорость на время между расчетами через `Time.deltaFixedTime`.

Comment: Уважаемый KingPeas, Спасибо за ответ! Я писал, что использовал и velocity, и AddForce. Да, и в  свойствах rigidbody изменял значения Collision Detection и Interpolate, обработку перемещений делал как в Update, Так и в FixedUpdate, положительных результатов не принесло.Я использую 2d физику, спрайты по 32х32 размером. соответственно 32 сантиметра на 32. Да и проблема заключается не в этом. Если взять спрайты и по 128 пикселей, и начать их сталкивать, то при столкновении между ними остается место. Все, что Вы перечислили - я перебрал, и это не дало положительного результата, к сожалению.

Answer (score 2):

Если твои белые блоки - сетка, то используй `TilemapCollider2D`. Нужно учитывать, что существуют микротрещины.
Попробуй еще использовать `CompositeColider2D` и учти, что галочка `Used By Composite` в `Tilemap Collider` должна быть включена